# deny read access to single project in a solution consisting of multiple projects

Tags: tfs

We use TFS as source control. In TFS we host a solution consisting of multiple Visual Studio projects. We do not want our contractors to see the source code of ONE of these projects (limited users should still see all compiled assemblies). What is the best way to achieve our objective without setting up two repositories and having to synchronize all code changes between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend that instead of just changing the permissions in place that you move the projects that you want to protect to a separate folder with its own solution. Secure that folder as above. You can then build it separately and  deploy it to an internal nuget repository.

you can then reference that repository from within the Visual Studio package manager and it will be managed as an external dependency. If you update and publish the other solution then the other devs will be notified of updates..

Answer (score 4):

You control access rights to a folder by selecting **Advanced->Security** from **Source Control Explorer**. From there, you can turn off security inheritance for the item(s) you need to protect. Then, create a TFS-specific group containing the 'limited users' only and only allow them access to the particular project folder. Alternatively, create a group for the contractors and deny them access.
This is based on VS/TFS 2012.

But my guess is that you will also need to create a specific solution for the contractors that doesn't have the particular project included.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is very similar to what I have figured out during the last 24 hours. One question that I am not sure about is how to provide the non-hidden projects in the newly created smaller solution with newest version of compiled assembly from the hidden project. Do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: I'd go for MrHinsh's suggestion below, using Nuget.